# PowerShell update variable while script is running

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

How do i update a variable in PowerShell while the script is running state?

I have a situation where the script monitors the size of a disk continuously and compares it with a number in a text file on a shared drive (say Z:\quota\software-share-size.txt). If the number in text file is greater than disk size it monitors, then it sends out an email to expand the disk to new size as mentioned in text file. But once the script starts, its not pulling in the new number from file and i dont want to stop and start the script to load new content from the text file. Help please

Comment: You update the value of a variable by assigning to it, ie. `$variable = <# some expression here #>`. Please show us the script you need help with

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you :

```
while($true)
{
#Here i pull my disk (C:) infomations (i use localhost for my computer, but you can use an IP or a file with multiple IP)

$diskinfo = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName localhost | where {$_.DeviceId -eq 'C:'} 

#Here you pull only the freespace value with Gb format (default is byte)
$freespace = $diskinfo.freespace/1Gb
$freespace = [int]$freespace

#here you pull the "limit number" off your file, must be in Gb and only the number is written in the file.
$limit=Get-Content -Path "B:\Dev\filewithsizeingo.txt"
$limit = [int]$limit


if ($freespace -gt $limit) #The free diskspace is greater than the limit
{
    Write-Host "Diskfreespace is Above Limit" -f Green
}
elseif ($freespace -lt $limit) #The free diskspace is inferior than the limit 
{
    Write-Host "Free diskspace below limit" -f Red
    #break
    #code mail sending
}
Start-Sleep 1
}
```

Because it's a loop, you can modify the filewithsizeingo.txt without stoping the script, and the script will refresh the free diskspace and limit value at each loop.

In the elseif statement, you can insert a break and code the sending of the email (which I do not know yet), dont forget the break or it will send a mail every second.

I hope it helps, or at least it gave you fresh's ideas (i'm a beginner with powershell, the code CAN be improved).